Supabase Request Origin Restriction
I am using supabase JS SDK to Make request to Supabase DataAPI. Now I want to allow access to only my origin www.abc.com to be able to access data using anon key. I want to restrict access to data even if someone has my anon key. How can I setup Supabase for the same?
When I run the api requests from postman or any other domain, data must not be accessible even through anon key. If the call is made from www.abc.com, then only data should be returned.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
